# Where the Ubuntu's source can be gotten?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, patch

Where can I get Ubuntu's source code? Actually I want It's kernel's code. I know I can get the kernel from kernel.org but as I found out that Ubuntu does some patching on the kernel I want to know what are those patches. And yes I know Ubuntu's kernel code can be found in an installed Ubuntu in the file system but thats just the code! I want specifically those patches separately and if any some comments or documents about them. Where can I get these things?

Answer (score 7):

**Source Tarball Way**

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
mkdir ~/src
cd ~/src
tar xjvf /usr/src/linux-source-<version-number-here>.tar.bz2
cd linux-source-<version-number-here>
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile#AltBuildMethod

**Git Clone Way**

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
mkdir ~/src/linux
cd ~/src/linux
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-maverick.git
```

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/KernelGitGuide?action=show&redirect=KernelTeam/KernelGitGuide

[More information about Git.](http://git-scm.com/)